# Slipt a sheet into different workbooks?

Tags: vba

Can I spit a sheet into diferent workbooks asking whick colum to use and then save the new workbooks in the drive?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to SE. The simple answer is "yes", but we're here to help you solve specific problems you encounter, not to write the solution for you. Try to solve your problem and then post your code and explain what specific item is not working.

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment on the OP.

Comment: It's a good comment and should be said. It should just be said in a comment.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment, hence the "answer"